# C# replace {CRLF} with {LF}

Tags: c#

I have a text file sent from others. If I open in NotePad++ and view all the symbols, I can see both {LF} and {CRLF} work as line separator.

Example:

line1: **ABC  {CRLF}**

line2: **XYZ  {LF}**

**Question:** If I want to replace `{CRLF}` with `{LF}` and write to a new file, why the output text file cannot show separate line and the separator symbols disappear. `Write` just writes the line and append another line without start a new line, but the line still has `{LF}` in it, hasn't it? Is that because I am working in Windows system? But how the original file with both `{LF}` and `{CR}{LF}` can be viewed as two separate lines?

Code is very simple:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"\\...\TEST.txt"))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"\\...\TEST2.txt"))
    {
        string line = "";

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sw.Write(line.Replace("\r\n", "\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StreamReader already knows how to correctly handle such files.  And strips the line terminator, so that Replace() call does nothing, all you need is StreamWriter.WriteLine().

Comment: How do you expect to find a `\r\n` in the string returned by `.ReadLine()`?

Comment: ok, ty all, did not realize that before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `ReadLine()` you're trimming the EOL characters (CR and LF). Instead you should do one of the following ways:

```
string file1 = @"\\...\TEST.txt";
string file2 = @"\\...\TEST2.txt";

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file1))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file2))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();        
        sw.Write(text.Replace("\r\n", "\n"));        
    }
}
```

Or

```
File.WriteAllText(file2,File.ReadAllText(file1).Replace("\r\n", "\n"));
```

But only if your file is not too big. Otherwise, Jim solution is the way to go.

Comment: And hope that the file is small enough to fit into memory.

Comment: @JimMischel Yeah, I was about to add to the post something like what you posted

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because when you call `sr.Readline()`, the returned string does not contain the CRLF characters. Those characters are added by `WriteLine`, which is essentially `Write(s + Environment.NewLine)`.

To make your code work, change it to

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    sw.Write(line + "\n");
}
```

You can simplify your code with:

```
File.WriteAllLines("outputFileName",
   FileReadLines("inputFileName").Select(s => s + "\n");
```